# How to save all my Active directory's users c:\

Tags: windows, powershell, server, robocopy

I Have to make a powershell script to save C:\ of each AD user :

First step, take User list from AD:

```
$Users = Foreach($OU in $OUList){
Get-ADUser -filter * -SearchBase $OU | Select-Object SamAccountName
}
```

Now that my variable $Users is filled with usernames I have to use robocopy to save their files on the C:\SAVES of my windows server

```
for(n=1; n<19;n++)
ROBOCOPY.exe "\\PCW10\$Users[n]"  "C:\SAV"
```

Thing is \PCW10\$Users[n] doesn't do what I want : instead of adapt it for each turn, like \PCW10\albertjohnson, etc an error returned

Comment: Should be `$n` instead of just `n`.

Comment: Yes sorry I forgotted to write it but in my script it's ok..

Comment: Should be `for($n=1; $n -lt 19;$n++){ROBOCOPY.exe "\\PCW10\$Users[n]"  "C:\SAV"}` or `foreach ($user in $Users){ROBOCOPY.exe "\\PCW10\$user"  "C:\SAV"}`

Comment: Thing is with your syntax it returns \\PCW10\albertjohnson johnattanmayers ... [n]  (The complete tab + [n])

Comment: "\\PCW10\$Users[n]" should be "\\PCW10\$($Users[n])"

Comment: also "for(n=1" should be "for($n=1"